# Hive showing org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException when trying to select from table

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-dynamodb

I tried to follow this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.Querying.html)

And when I reached creating external table step:

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ams_audit_trail (job_id integer, application_id integer, actions String)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "ams_audit_trail",
"dynamodb.column.mapping" = "job_id:job_id,application_id:application_id,actions:actions");`

It executed well, when I tried to select from it:
`select * from ams_audit_trail limit 10;'

I got this error:

`Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating job_id`

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the following saved the problem, but when I changed the job_id data type from integer to String it worked fine!